# File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel, directory, temp

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
(1/1) FileException
File could not be uploaded: missing temporary directory.

in UploadedFile.php (line 235)
at UploadedFile->move('public/images/products/', 'products_8885101619419081.png')
in ProductCtrl.php (line 54)

My Code is:

```
      if($_FILES['attachFile']['name'] != NULL){
          $file = $request->file('attachFile');
          $photo ="products_".rand(1111,999999).strtotime('now').".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $des = "public/images/products/";
          $file->move($des,$photo);

          $mediaData['path'] = $photo;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  if($_FILES['attachFile']['name'] != NULL){
      $file = $request->file('attachFile');
      $photo = "products_".rand(1111,999999).strtotime('now').".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $des = "public/images/products/" . $photo;
      $file->move($des,$file);

      $mediaData['path'] = $photo;
   }
```